# Hide DOM object in jquery but determined by other object

Tags: jquery, hide

How can I use jQuery to cause the link with class `.morelink_L3` to be hidden if the div that contains the text `We understand things...` is less than 550 characters?

The fact that this div has no `class` or `id` makes it tricky for me. There is the option of using `find()` but that didn't work when I used it. This is what I tried:

```
if ($(".story_L3 > div").text().trim().length < 550) {
  $('.morelink_L3').hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div  "l3-details">
    <div class="story_L3">
      <div>Section Description</div>
      <div>We understand things change in life and at work and we want to make sure you’re ready for anything. We have a host of information available to help you understand what you need to do and how we can support you through any change.</div>
    </div>
    <span class="morelink_L3" value="True">Read More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the `story_L3` matching the condition then target immediately following `morelink_L3` sibling using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

And use [`:eq(index)` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) / [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to target second `div`

```js
$(".story_L3").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children('div:eq(1)').text().trim().length < 550
}).next('.morelink_L3').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div "l3-details">
    <div class="story_L3">
      <div>Section Description</div>
      <div>We understand things change in life and at work and we want to make sure you’re ready for anything. We have a host of information available to help you understand what you need to do and how we can support you through any change.</div>
    </div>
    <span class="morelink_L3" value="True">Read More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq()` to target an element by its index in its parent. In this case the second `div` would be `:eq(1)`. Try this:

```js
if ($(".story_L3 > div:eq(1)").text().trim().length < 550) {
  $('.morelink_L3').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div "l3-details">
    <div class="story_L3">
      <div>Section Description</div>
      <div>We understand things change in life and at work and we want to make sure you’re ready for anything. We have a host of information available to help you understand what you need to do and how we can support you through any change.</div>
    </div>
    <span class="morelink_L3" value="True">Read More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that you could use a single call to `toggle()` providing the boolean condition to hide/show the relevant element:

```
$('.morelink_L3').toggle($(".story_L3 > div:eq(1)").text().trim().length > 550);
```